# users.get в vk_api возвращает пустое значение. Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

При попытке выполнить метод users.get возвращается пустое значение.

```
def user_name(from_id):
    Sname=vk_session.method('users.get',{"from_id": from_id})
    print(from_id)
    print(Sname)
```

`from_id` успешно возвращает id пользователя написавшего сообщение.

Вывод выглядит так:

```
5165***99
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

От куда у вас параметр from_id взялся? Открываем документацию к методу, и смотрим какие параметры он принимает https://dev.vk.com/method/users.get

```
def user_name(from_id):
    Sname=vk_session.method('users.get',{"user_ids": from_id})
    print(from_id)
    print(Sname)
```